# SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//img[contains('1236548597')]' is not a valid XPath expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am getting syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//img[contains('1236548597')]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

My code:

```
enter_chat = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains('1236548597')]")
enter_chat.click()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//img[contains('1236548597')]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

...implies that the **XPath** which you have used was not a valid *XPath* expression.

In your code trial the predicate with `contains()` function has an issue.

- `contains()` accepts two parameters. The first parameter is always the *attribute* to be tested and the second parameter is the *value* to lookout for. The first parameter should have been the *attribute* which contains the value **1236548597**:

  ```
  enter_chat = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@<attributeName>,'1236548597')]")
  ```

It would be tough to construct an answer without the relevant HTML. However two possible solutions are as follows:

- If the tag is a `<a>` tag, containing an `img` *attribute* containing the value **1236548597**:

  ```
  enter_chat = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@img,'1236548597')]")
  ```
- If the tag is a `<img>` tag, containing an `src` *attribute* containing the value **1236548597**:

  ```
  enter_chat = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'1236548597')]")
  ```

Answer (score -1):

It should be,

```
enter_chat = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(text(),'1236548597')]")
enter_chat.click()

if "//img[contains(text(),'1236548597')]" not work, 
try "//img[contains(.,'1236548597')]"
```

You have missed text() function.