# selenium - Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string is not a valid XPath expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, xpath-1.0

There is the following page.

http://remitly.com/us/en/

When you click on a select, a list with countries appears. I try to select one country, for example, Colombia and click on it. But I get an error.

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
>   '//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8' and text(),
>   'Colombia')]' is not a valid XPath expression.

```
select = driver.find_element_by_class_name('f1wrnyr7')
select.click()
countries = driver.find_element_by_class_name('f1o6pohl')
country = countries.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8' and text(), 'Colombia')]")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8' and text(), 'Colombia')]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

...implies that the **XPath** which you have used was not a valid *XPath* expression.

Seems you were pretty close. You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath 1*:

  ```
  country = countries.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8') and text()='Colombia']")
  ```
- Using *xpath 2*:

  ```
  country = countries.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8') and contains(., 'Colombia')]")
  ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//img[contains('1236548597')]' is not a valid XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069778/syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-string-imgconta/52072955#52072955)

---

### Update

To overcome the **element not visible** error you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategy*:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8') and text()='Colombia']")))
```

Comment: But when I click on an element, I get an `element not visible` error. tried to set `time.sleep(5)`

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Check the change log. After observing the url I have shifted the loyalty from `countries` to `driver`.

Comment: I wrote `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8') and text()='Colombia']")))` and `element.click()` and got error `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук There wasn't any clicking attempt in your code. Why would you attempt a click? Definitely answer would be different.

Comment: Sorry. But I do not understand why an error flies on this line ... `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8') and text()='Colombia']"))).sendKeys(Keys.Enter)`

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук Now you are messing up things. `sendKeys()` requires element to be clickable. This should be a new question altogether.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you were trying something like this (change xpaths as follows, based on your needs):

notice here that the text node should be equal to 'Colombia':
`//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8') and text()='Colombia']`

or, the text node might contain some long text, but should also contain 'Colombia' in that text:

`//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8') and contains(text(), 'Colombia')]`

Comment: But when I click on an element, I get an `element not visible` error. tried to set `time.sleep(5)`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to attach a link to the page. Anyway, the XPath expression is invalid, the corrected version may be:

```
//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8') and text()='Colombia']\
```

You can test it with the following XML:

```
<span class="md_countryName_fdxiah8">Colombia</span>
```

Result:

```
Element='<span class="md_countryName_fdxiah8">Colombia</span>'
```

Comment: But when I click on an element, I get an `element not visible` error. tried to set `time.sleep(5)`

Comment: Would be great to see the target page, can't see the link in your question. Maybe you need something like  `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8') and text()='Colombia']")))`

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, Select element are better handled with Select function object. Then each of the list contnet can be addressed by its text

You should import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

And then

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('f1wrnyr7'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Colombia')
```

Comment: The fact that it is not select