# SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[contains(., 'Medium')' is not a valid XPath expression error using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

i using selenium try to get the div class value in html, but i hit the problem as per below

```
invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[contains(., 'Medium') because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[contains(., 'Medium')' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Below is my html and my code that read value of html.

HTML:

[image]

Code trials:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(., 'Medium')"));
String text =   element.GetAttribute("text");
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[contains(., 'Medium') because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[contains(., 'Medium')' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

...implies that the **XPath** which you have used was not a valid *XPath* expression.

---

You were so close. You missed the closing **`]`** while constructing the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath).

Effectively your line of code will be:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(., 'Medium')]"));
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of related relevant discussions in:

- [selenium - Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string is not a valid XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570395/selenium-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-string-is-not-a-valid/57570569#57570569)
- [SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//img[contains('1236548597')]' is not a valid XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069778/syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-string-imgconta/52072955#52072955)

Answer (score 1):

You xpath expression less closing `]`:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(., 'Medium')]"));
String text = element.Text;
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

And to extract text use `element.Text;` or `element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");`

Comment: It working, thanks!!! but i still not able get the text value in in console.

Comment: @JonathanK try `element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");` or `element.Text;`

Comment: Actually I wanted to get the value of " Medium is not like other platform on the internet"  thank you for the help

Comment: thank you..do you know how to set the value to the element ? i wanted to change the value " Medium is not like other platform on the internet"  to other wording.

Comment: @JonathanK no, it's inside `<div>` tag, if by manually you can't change the text, likewise with selenium.