# Python Selenium SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[contains(@class, 'product-card__subtitle')

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

Trying to get the XPath of div class and the text inside of the div. the two divs are:

```
<div class="product-card__subtitle">Women's Shoe</div>
<div class="product-card__subtitle">Men's Shoe</div>
```

My Xpaths that are giving the selenium error are:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'product-card__subtitle') and text("
                                                      ")='Women's Shoe']")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'product-card__subtitle') and text()='Men's "
                                                    "Shoe']")
```

I am trying to get the path for the part that says "Women's shoe" and another path for the part that says "Men's shoe"
[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[contains(@class, 'product-card__subtitle')
```

...implies that the *XPath* which you have used was not a valid *XPath expression*.

---

### Solution

To locate the desired elements you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `Women's Shoe`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-card__subtitle' and contains(., \"Women's Shoe\")]")
  ```
- `Men's Shoe`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-card__subtitle' and  contains(., \"Men's Shoe\")]")
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//img[contains('1236548597')]' is not a valid XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069778/syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-string-imgconta/52072955#52072955)
- [selenium - Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string is not a valid XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570395/selenium-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-string-is-not-a-valid/57570569#57570569)

Answer (score 1):

The **root cause** is the text has symbol `'`.
Although you can optimize other xpath syntax expression, you don't have to.

EDIT 1:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'product-card__subtitle') and text()=\"Women's Shoe\"]")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'product-card__subtitle') and text()=\"Men's Shoe\"]")
```

---

I thought the below is right, but when verifying in chrome console, I still got error "not a valid XPath expression"

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'product-card__subtitle') and text()='Women\'s Shoe']")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'product-card__subtitle') and text()='Men\'s Shoe']")
```

Comment: I am getting this error ```selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[contains(@class, 'product-card__subtitle') and text()='Men's Shoe'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[contains(@class, 'product-card__subtitle') and text()='Men's Shoe']' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)```

Comment: Yes, sorry. The original answer still has syntax error, I will fix it. In fact, I think a shorter xpath should work fine, just try `"//div[text()=\"Men's Shoe\"]"`