# Error when trying to to get html element using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Im trying to get a HTML element from twitter.com search bar. Using selenium I'm using the `find_element_by_xpath` method.

**Code**

```
search_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@aria-label="Search query"]')
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jorda\OneDrive - Limerick Institute Of Technology\College\Semester 6\Data Analytics\Data Scraping\twit'ter.py", line 25, in <module>
    search_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@data-testid="SearchBox_Search_Input""]')
  File "C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@data-testid="SearchBox_Search_Input""] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[@data-testid="SearchBox_Search_Input""]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.198)
```

The element I'm trying to get is supposed to be `aria-label="Search query"`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you read the error, it says : `"is not a valid XPath expression."`

Comment: seei im just following a video and the code is the exact same. I don't see what the error is

Comment: send me the link of site that you want to find xpath in it

Comment: https://twitter.com/home

Comment: Im following this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KaffTIZ5II&list=WL&index=73&t=162s&ab_channel=IzzyAnalytics                           about 5:50 in

Comment: `//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/input`

Comment: If i were you, i would use the following xpath

Comment: It seems the home page makes the input tag disappear if it's not fullscreen.

Comment: The string '//input[@data-testid="SearchBox_Search_Input""]' is not a valid XPath expression . Your xpath is not valid because you have 2 double quote after SearchBox_Search_Input

Comment: Info provided in your question is misleading: the predicate in code `[@aria-label="Search query"]` while predicate in exception log is `[@data-testid="SearchBox_Search_Input""]`. Update your question with exact data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@data-testid="SearchBox_Search_Input""] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[@data-testid="SearchBox_Search_Input""]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

...implies that the *xpath* which you have used wasn't a valid xpath expression.

The error was observed for the xpath as:

```
//input[@data-testid="SearchBox_Search_Input""]
```

is different from the xpath you have provided as code trials.

However the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) with in your code trial is a valid xpath and won't raise this error.

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  search_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-label='Search query']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  search_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Search query']")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//img[contains('1236548597')]' is not a valid XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069778/syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-string-imgconta/52072955#52072955)
- [selenium - Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string is not a valid XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570395/selenium-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-string-is-not-a-valid/57570569#57570569)
- [Python Selenium SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422288/python-selenium-syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-str/63431435#63431435)