# SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document' error passing parameter as xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, syntax-error, testng

I am trying to pass an xpath as a parameter(redirectButton):

```
WebElement zoomLogo = driver.findElement(By.xpath(redirectButton));
```

Line in testsuite.xml looks like this:

```
            <parameter name="redirectButton" 
        value="&quot;//img[@alt='zoom logo colour long']&quot;)" />
```

But when I try to run the test through the testsuite file using testng it shows the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '"//img[@alt='zoom logo colour long']")' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

I am sure I have proper xpath because when I paste it directly into the code then everything works fine, but when I try to do it via parameter its not working.

Is it possible to do it by parameters?

Comment: The line in the testsuite.xml should be `<parameter name="redirectButton" value="//img[@alt='zoom logo colour long']" />` (without the `&quot;` and the `)` at the end) because the xpath itself is `//img[@alt='zoom logo colour long']`. If you write the xpath as String in Java you have to place it in quotes, but that is how strings are defined in Java and is not part of the xpath expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '"//img[@alt='zoom logo colour long']")' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

...implies that the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) which you have used was not a valid *XPath* expression.

Seems you were almost there. You need to remove the two `&quot;` characters and the extra `)` to make it a valid xpath expression as follows:

```
<parameter name="redirectButton" value="//img[@alt='zoom logo colour long']" />
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//img[contains('1236548597')]' is not a valid XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069778/syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-string-imgconta/52072955#52072955)
- [selenium - Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string is not a valid XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570395/selenium-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-string-is-not-a-valid/57570569#57570569)
- [Python Selenium SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div contains(@class, 'product-card__subtitle')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422288/python-selenium-syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-str/63431435#63431435)

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation!!