# Changing xpaths

Tags: python, selenium

I got an id that keeps changing each time my page refreshes i tried using

```
start-with@id
contains@id
```

`//*[@id="mat-input-2"]` the 2 after the input changes each time i refresh the page I've tried everyting

everytime when I try someting new i get errors like this.

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[starts-with(@id="mat-input-")]' is not a valid XPath expression

I have googled everywhere tried everyting i don't know what else to do so my last resort is trying this forum

Thank you for your help have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[starts-with(@id="mat-input-")]' is not a valid XPath expression
```

...implies that the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) which you have used was not a valid *XPath* expression.

Seems you were almost there. You just need to replace the `=` character with **`,`** character to make it a valid xpath expression you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `starts-with()`:

  ```
  //*[starts-with(@id, "mat-input-")]
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  //*[contains(@id, "mat-input-")]
  ```
- Using *cssSelector* and *starts-with*:

  ```
  [id^='mat-input-']
  ```
- Using *cssSelector* and *contains*:

  ```
  [id*='mat-input-']
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//img[contains('1236548597')]' is not a valid XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069778/syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-string-imgconta/52072955#52072955)
- [selenium - Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string is not a valid XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570395/selenium-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-string-is-not-a-valid/57570569#57570569)
- [Python Selenium SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div contains(@class, 'product-card__subtitle')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422288/python-selenium-syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-evaluate-on-document-the-str/63431435#63431435)

Answer (score 0):

You used it incorrectly. It should be

```
'//*[starts-with(@id, "mat-input-")]'
```

Note comma instead of equal sign

P.S. Same for `contains`